# Gem::LoadError Specified 'mysql2' for database adapter, but the gem is not loaded. Add `gem 'mysql2'` to your Gemfile

Tags: ruby, ubuntu

Esse erro aparece constantemente, no meu caso, instalei o ruby, as gems, rails, o mysql2 tudo certo. Mas quando tentava:

```
rake db:create
```

aparecia outro erro:

**Gem::LoadError: Specified 'mysql2' for database adapter, but the gem is not loaded. Add `gem 'mysql2'` to your Gemfile (and ensure its version is at the minimum required by ActiveRecord).
Gem::LoadError: can't activate mysql2 (~> 0.3.13), already activated mysql2-0.4.0. Make sure all dependencies are added to Gemfile.**

Nesse caso, qualquer tentativa que buscava gerava erro, a solução que encontrei foi, acessar o Gemfile e alterar para:

```
# Use mysql as the database for Active Record
gem 'mysql2', '~> 0.3.13'
```

salvei e executei:

```
bundle exec rake db:create
```

voalá db criado!

Espero poder ajudar mais alguém com esse post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Na verdade, por algum motivo que desconheço, está havendo um problema de incompatibilidade do Rails 4.2.4 com essa mais nova 0.4.0 do mysql2, portanto se você utilizar a segunda versão mais nova 0.3.20, vai dar certo.

```
gem 'mysql2', '~> 0.3.20'
bundle install
```

Espero ter ajudado de alguma forma.

Valeu.